# Magento: convert indian numbers to arabic numbers in the admin sales order grid?

Tags: php, magento

i have added a new column (telephone) to the admin sales order grid
by editing the app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php file
[gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/accfddaf87e65d2fedd5)

edited/added code is:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone'))->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing'");
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
  $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
         'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('telephone'),
         'index' => 'telephone',
         'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.telephone',
    ));
}
```

now it looks like this

[image]

now the problem is there are some telephone numbers in arabic (indian numbers) and others in english (arabic numbers)
and the filtering depends on which numbers you are searching with
so i need to convert the indian numbers to arabic numbers so the filter can work on all rows

how i could do this in the Grid.php file?

Answer (score 1):

if you are referring to what [Wikipedia calls eastern arabic / indic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals), a simple replace operation should do.

```
 $western_arabic = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
 $eastern_arabic = array('٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩');

 $str = str_replace($western_arabic, $eastern_arabic, $str);
```

Comment: the problem is where to put this in the Grid.php file, there is no a variable to apply this on it, it just some kind of top level functions